# PHP web application working in a read only file system

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a web application, that uses Yii2, that I would like to make it work on a read only file system.

For the caching components, is quite easy. There is other options, like database, or Redis, etc.

But I have some specific uses, like for example, the HTML purifier, that, to purify a string, needs a runtime folder access, to process stuff.

How to attend these specific cases? Ditch everything that can't be done in memory, or not in a cloud storage, like S3, for example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to run in on a completely read-only system? This seems like an odd form of idealism. Why not just provide permissions for the things which actually need them?

Comment: The main reason is to enhance security.

Comment: If you are being hacked, this is not the solution

Comment: In that case, apply it where it's needed, not as a blanket thing at the expense of legitimate features. Give the application write access to the things it needs write access to in order for a specific feature to work, and nothing else.

Comment: Run your Yii app in a serverless environment, you can run the whole app on Cloud Run. https://cloud.google.com/run